# Firebase queryEqual(toValue:

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to using the queryEqual(toValue: in swift.  The issue I'm having is that I am getting null.

My data looks like this this

```
"time" : {
      "149791341619654" : {
        "URL_ID" : "02D03DA8-A652-4EFA-946F-1F0F2A963449",
        "UUID" : "F496B98E-3B4E-4602-B06D-C09B7F42DCB5",
        "date" : 1.497913416196546E9,
        "huer" : 0,
        "latitude" : 32.87926715336076,
        "longitude" : -117.2139702738423,
        "type_" : "Image",
        "uid" : "BjN8usKaW7NhqD2DxPPqAkjhnSx2"
      },
      "149791381894099" : {
        "URL_ID" : "AB8D20E9-D1EB-4FD0-B0A8-CE755D1D8B91",
        "UUID" : "F534E1FC-DC55-4AFB-847D-64B614EF7137",
        "date" : 1.497913818940991E9,
        "huer" : 0,
        "latitude" : 32.87926715336076,
        "longitude" : -117.2139702738423,
        "type_" : "Image",
        "uid" : "BjN8usKaW7NhqD2DxPPqAkjhnSx2"
      },
      "149791881234864" : {
        "URL_ID" : "A3207072-FC64-4A09-87C0-E1340051B140",
        "UUID" : "D0C3FA34-2790-4896-96F7-E0E7C3E17687",
        "date" : 1.497918812348642E9,
        "huer" : 0,
        "latitude" : 32.87915823052905,
        "longitude" : -117.2140478064466,
        "type_" : "Video",
        "uid" : "BjN8usKaW7NhqD2DxPPqAkjhnSx2"
      }
    }
```

I want to be able get only the child "149791381894099" for example.
The code in swift I am currently using is (sorry the formatting was acting weird)

```
self.rootRef.child(uidOtherProfile).child("time").queryEqual(toValue: 149791381894099).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in})
```

but I have used

```
self.rootRef.child(uidOtherProfile).child("time").queryEqual(toValue: "149791381894099").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

Comment: Your JSON doesn't contain a `time` property. It does contain a `date` property. Is that what you're trying to filter on? Because if so: `.child("time").queryOrdered(byChild:"date").queryEqual(toValue: 149791381894099)` (note the absence of quotes around that last value).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But no I want to either sort by the value of the children of time or by the value of date.  Not sure if you noticed but I have the same values as the "names" of the nodes as what sits in date.  I want to avoid the .queryOrdered(byChild:"date") because I have set up the data entry so that firebase will automatically sort properly and I don't want to waste the computation.  I just want to query using "queryStarting, queryEnding, queryEqual" a given date value.

Comment: What you have right now could be easier done with `self.rootRef.child(uidOtherProfile).child("time").child("149791381894099")`. But what's the problem?

Comment: I'm not just about the queryEqual but also queryStarting and queryEnding.  They all follow the same mechanics (or so I believe).  My overall goal is to use queryLimited(toFirst) in conjunction with .queryStarting but I am only asking about one part at the moment.  Example being **self.rootRef.child(uidOtherProfile).child("time").queryStarting(atValue: 149791381894099).queryLimited(toFirst:1).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in})**

Answer (score 1):

The default sort order for Firebase is by priority. To query the keys you need to call `queryOrderedByKey()`:

```
ref.queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: "149791381894099").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot)
})
```