# How to use queryEqual(toValue:childKey:) in Firebase SDK for iOS properly?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm new in NoSQL and Firebase. I have database like this for path "writers".

[image]

I tried to find any user with email "test@test.com" using this code:

```
ref.child("writers").queryEqual(toValue: "test@test.com", childKey: "email").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in
    print (String(describing: snap.value));
}
```

But all I got is `Optional(<null>)` on the console. What's wrong with my code? I thought it's pretty straightforward, but I can't get it to work despite any fix I tried.

I can get all the writers data successfully though, if I use code:

```
ref.child("writers").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
    print (String(describing: snap.value));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Swift: queryEqualToValue by childKey is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577138/firebase-swift-queryequaltovalue-by-childkey-is-not-working)

Comment: Don't use array's in Firebase. Second thing you have 4 numeric keys and then an unrelated key string. Not sure why but that sounds like you are not creating keys in a consistent manner. Don't forget to add .orderBy.

Answer (score 5):

The correct syntax is:

```
ref.child("writers").queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue: "test@test.com").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in
  ...
```

The overload you used is for a different (and much less common) use-case.

Also see some other questions about querying Firebase in Swift:

- [Firebase queryEqual(toValue:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642561/firebase-queryequaltovalue)
- [Firebase queryEqualToValue with childKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421387/firebase-queryequaltovalue-with-childkey)